# Bank class OOP interface decisions

Tags: java, oop, interface

I'm writing a simple `Bank` class which contains `Account`s. I'd like `Person`s to be able to open a new password-protected bank account and withdraw and deposit money from their account. Accounts are housed within the Bank. Which services should the Bank and Account classes provide?

Let's say Person p already has an account in Bank b and he wants to make a deposit of $100. His password is "monkey". Choices:

```
b.accessAccount(p, "monkey").deposit(100);
```

where accessAccount() validates the password and then returns p's Account

or

```
b.deposit(p, "monkey", 100);
```

Which is the more logical choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is the right choice, one method should do one thing, besides the first one is much more understandable than the second one.

Comment: continuing on this, the first one appears to be creating an authenticated session object which then allows actions to be performed. this is good.

Comment: Are there any security concerns in returning a bare Account object to the user?